# Mysql C# update int value by 1

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I use this method to increase value of logins column by one:

```
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(connectionStringMySql);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

cmd.Connection = connect;
cmd.Connection.Open();

string commandLine = null;
commandLine = "UPDATE Users SET logins = (@cur_value := logins) + 1 WHERE id = @id;";

cmd.CommandText = commandLine;


cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userId);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Connection.Close();
```

And i get this Exception:

> Fatal error encountered during command execution.

Comment: What about @cur_value? You didn't set parameter for it.

Comment: You aren't supplying the value of `@cur_value`, maybe that's it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this code

```
string commmandLine = "UPDATE Users SET logins = logins + 1 WHERE id = @id";
cmd.Set
```

Answer (score 0):

First try this code

commandLine = "UPDATE Users SET **logins =1** WHERE id = @id";

If above code is does not threw any error, then  try below code

```
commandLine = "UPDATE Users SET **logins =@YourValue** WHERE id = @id";

cmd.CommandText = commandLine;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", userId);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YourValue", 1);//**Put your logins value**
```

Answer (score -1):

Add following line:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cur_value", yourValue);
```

Also make more clear sql statement:

```
UPDATE Users 
SET logins = @cur_value + 1 
WHERE id = @id;
```

It is good practice to enclose problematic pieces of code with `try/catch`. Classes which represents unmanaged resources like Stream or SqlConnection are implementing `IDisposable` interface. They are usually need to be enclosed with `using` statement to be able to correctly release their resources even if exception was thrown (or use try/finally and in finally block call to method `Close` or `Dispose`). Then your code will be nice and clear :)