# c# add to int in mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, phpmyadmin, int

So I am making an application that shows a viral video each day.It uses a MySQL database  keep count on the views, I have a MySQL database with a column called `video1_count` with only 1 value. I want to know how to add to the current int not add new data I have a class called  add user that I will use to execute the code how can I do this?

I did find this [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748580/mysql-c-sharp-update-int-value-by-1) But for the life of me i could not get it to work.

i Tried this code :

```
MySqlConnection connect = new MySqlConnection(Connect_String);
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

cmd.Connection = connect;
cmd.Connection.Open();

string commandLine = null;
string commmandLine = "UPDATE Youtube SET Video1_count = Video1_count + 1 ";
cmd.Set // (Recommended by a user) but cmd.set is not valid 

cmd.Connection.Close();
```

Comment: show how did you try, then people may see what was wrong and suggest on how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

You're not executing a command anywhere.

command.ExecuteNonQuery() will actually send your command to the database

Try this

```
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(Connect_String);
MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "UPDATE Youtube SET Video1_count = Video1_count + 1";
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: "No database selected"

Comment: oh name of the database is Slq4342562 and the table name is Youtube and the column is called Video1_count how would this go, sorry i am new to using MySQL in my applications

Comment: @Gerard2202 Check your connection string, does it mention database name Slq4342562?

Comment: @har07 here is my string for the connection `String Connect_String = "datasource=sql3.freesqldatabase.com;port=******;username=******;password=********";`

Comment: Looks like a bad connection string.  Check out the options on connectionstrings.com, under MySQL.  General format appears to be along the lines of `"Server=sql3.freesqldatabase.com;Port=****;Database=Sql4342562;Uid=****;Pwd=****;"`